# Why can I not put POSIXct objects into a data frame in R?

Tags: r

We have the code:

```
times <- c("2:30 PM", "10:00 AM", "10:00 AM")
mydat <- data.frame(times=times)
```

which results in

```
> mydat
     times
1  2:30 PM
2 10:00 AM
3 10:00 AM
```

I want to convert these times, which are characters, into POSIX format. So I do

```
mydat$ntimes <- as.POSIXct(NA,"")
mydat$ntimes <- sapply(mydat$times, function(x) parse_date_time(x, '%I:%M %p'))
```

Then we get

```
> mydat
     times       ntimes
1  2:30 PM -62167167000
2 10:00 AM -62167183200
3 10:00 AM -62167183200
```

I have no idea why these are negative. Furthermore, if instead of `sapply` we did a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(mydat$times)){
 mydat$ntimes[i] <- parse_date_time(mydat$times[i], '%I:%M %p')
}
```

we get the format right, but everything is off by 7 minutes and 2 seconds, why is that?

```
> mydat
     times              ntimes
1  2:30 PM 0000-01-01 06:37:02
2 10:00 AM 0000-01-01 02:07:02
3 10:00 AM 0000-01-01 02:07:02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this :

```
as.POSIXct(mydat$times, format = '%I:%M %p', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2021-03-14 14:30:00 UTC" "2021-03-14 10:00:00 UTC" "2021-03-14 10:00:00 UTC"
```

Or

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(mydat$times, '%I:%M %p')
#[1] "0000-01-01 14:30:00 UTC" "0000-01-01 10:00:00 UTC" "0000-01-01 10:00:00 UTC"
```

The difference in two options is that when the date is absent `as.POSIXct` will give today's date whereas `parse_date_time` will give `0000-01-01`.

Answer (score 1):

**Base R Solution**

You can use the `strptime` function to convert the `times` variable of character type to `POSIXlt`. Without a date provided, this function also returns todays date.

```r
times <- c("2:30 PM", "10:00 AM", "10:00 AM")
mydat <- data.frame(times=times)

# FORMAT SPECIFICATIONS: 
# %I = Hours as decimal number (01–12).
# %M = Minute as decimal number (00–59).
# %p = AM/PM indicator in the locale. 

strptime(mydat$times, format='%I:%M %p', tz = 'UTC')

#> [1] "2021-03-13 14:30:00 UTC" "2021-03-13 10:00:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2021-03-13 10:00:00 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Add it to the data frame as a new variable**

```r
times <- c("2:30 PM", "10:00 AM", "10:00 AM")
mydat <- data.frame(times=times)

mydat$new_times <- strptime(mydat$times, format='%I:%M %p')


#>      times           new_times
#> 1  2:30 PM 2021-03-13 14:30:00
#> 2 10:00 AM 2021-03-13 10:00:00
#> 3 10:00 AM 2021-03-13 10:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>